# Typescript conditional return type based on input object property

Tags: typescript

I have a function that has a object containing a `type` property which is an enum.

Based on the value of the enum I want to define the return type of the function.

I tried the following:

```
enum CustomType = {
  TypeA = 'TYPEA',
  TypeB = 'TYPEB',
  TypeC = 'TYPEC'
}

function construct<T extends CustomType>(param: Record<string, any> & {type: T}): T extends CustomType.TypeA ? ClassA : T extends CustomType.TypeB ? ClassB : ClassC {
  switch(param.type) {
    case CustomType.TypeA:
      return new ClassA()
    case CustomType.TypeB:
      return new ClassB()
    case CustomType.TypeC:
      return new ClassC()
  }
}
```

I get the following errors:
`TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.` and on each return statement `TS2322: Type 'ClassA' is not assignable to type 'T extends CustomType.TypeA ? ClassA : T extends CustomType.TypeB ? ClassB : ClassC'.`

Is it actually possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLvqaw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed these errors by introducing the `typeToClassMap` object that maps type to a corresponding class and also added `default` branch to the `switch` statement:

```
const typeToClassMap = {
    [CustomType.TypeA]: new ClassA,
    [CustomType.TypeB]: new ClassB,
    [CustomType.TypeC]: new ClassC,
}

function construct<T extends CustomType>(param: Record<string, any> & {type: T}): typeof typeToClassMap[T] {
     switch(param.type) {
    case CustomType.TypeA:
      return new ClassA()
    case CustomType.TypeB:
      return new ClassB()
    case CustomType.TypeC:
      return new ClassC()
    default:
     const _exhaustiveMatch: never = param.type;
     throw new Error('Non-exhausive match for type');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, but I am still curious whether there are other/better solutions.

```
function construct<T extends CustomType>(
        param: {
            type: T
        } & Record<string, any>
    ): T extends CustomType.TypeA ? ClassA : T extends CustomType.TypeB ? ClassB : ClassC
function construct<T extends CustomType>(param: Record<string, any>): ClassA | ClassB | ClassC {
  switch(param.type) {
    case CustomType.TypeA:
      return new ClassA()
    case CustomType.TypeB:
      return new ClassB()
    case CustomType.TypeC:
      return new ClassC()
  }
}
```

Comment: "better" way with a mapping instead of chaining conditionals: https://tsplay.dev/wO5PEm